# How to parse an input string into individual tokens? (Java)

Tags: java, parsing

I'm trying to parse an expression string into individual token units to be put into an array list. So basically, I'm given an expression like such:

```
(3 + 5)
```

and once it's done parsing, it should look like this in the array list:

```
"(", "3", "+", "5", ")"
```

In this case, whitespace should be ignored. Also, if the expression contained an operator like "++" or "--", they should be stored as one token, not two. For example, (++3) would be come "(", "++", "3", ")".

I'm not sure if my approach is correct, but what I'm thinking is to use a for loop to go through each character and see if it matches.

UPDATE:

```
    for(int i=0; i<expressionString.length(); i++) {
        //cast char into ascii int
        int ascii = (int) charAt(i);

        //appending to token if one of operator symbols
        if( ascii >= 40 && ascii <= 47 || ascii == 91 || ascii == 93){
            token.append((char) ascii);

        //appending to token if it's a num  
        } else if ( ascii >= 48 || ascii <=57) {
            token.append((char) ascii);

            //check if next char is a num, if so, append to token
            while ((int) charAt(i+1) >= 48 || (int) charAt(i+1) <=57) {
                //increment i in for loop to check
                i++;
                token.append((int) charAt(i));
            }

        }
        //  
    }
```

Comment: So you want to split the string at number-operator boundaries. What kind of operators are you looking for? Just `+-*/`?

Comment: your for loop should work by taking each character once but you would have to hard code the special scenarios ex, ++, -- and so on. Use the charAt() of string to check each letter of the string.

Comment: It would be for operators like: +, -, *, /, ++, -- and such.

Comment: Which approach? I don't see any attempt of you to solve this yourself? It rather looks like you dumped your (home)work hoping that we do the work part for you.

Comment: Beyond that: you are looking to build a parser. That is well researched and documented topic. Did you do any research?

Comment: I've added code as I wasn't sure if that was the correct way of going about the question now that people have some-what validated what I had to say. If I do this, am I prone to indexOutOfBounds problem? or no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, what you are looking for is `toCharArray()`, which is the simplest solution, but, it won't give you desire output, if there are multiple operation

```
String str ="(3+5)";
str = str.replaceAll("\\s+",""); // remove all whitespaces
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.toCharArray()));
```

So, you need to use loop and keep checking the character with next character and append them if they are same type. Then, you need `ArrayList` where you will keep adding the `String` (which you appended so far)

```
    List<String> lstStr = new ArrayList<>();
    str= str.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<str.length()-1; i++)
    {

  // actually we looking, if they are same type  
 if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))==Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i+1)))
       {
            temp.append(str.charAt(i));
       }
       else
       {
            temp.append(str.charAt(i));
            lstStr.add(temp.toString());
            temp.setLength(0);// reset StringBuilder to re-use
       }
    }

    temp.append(str.charAt(i));
    lstStr.add(temp.toString());
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lstStr.toArray()));
```

Since, we are actually loop till `N-2`, where `N` is length of the `String`, so, we need to append the last character to `StringBuilder` and then add it to the `List`.

Comment: But this does not account for double operators. This will treat double operators as 2 tokens. The OP wants it as one. Also, it splits up numbers with 2 or more digits.

Comment: Your approach is way to simple. it takes more than the suggested things to really parse expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `java.util.Scanner`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("10++9+0-4");
// here I used regex that says "match any boundary or whitespace between an operator and a number"
// So the scanner will keep scanning until it reaches such a boundary, where it will return the result
scanner.useDelimiter("((?<=[+\\-*/])\\s*(?=\\d))|((?<=\\d)\\s*(?=[+\\-*/]))");
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
}
```

Try the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/z8FBET/3). See if it splits the string at your desired locations.

Answer (score 0):

One running solution

> ```
> public class ParseInputString {
>
>     public static void main(String args[])
>      {
>         String a="(3 ++ 5)";
>         char [] arr=a.replaceAll("\\s+","").toCharArray();
>
>         Set<Character> charSet = new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
>         for (char c : arr) {
>             charSet.add(c);
>         }
>         List<Character> arrrList=new ArrayList<Character>();
>         Iterator<Character> it = charSet.iterator();
>         while(it.hasNext()){
>             arrrList.add(it.next());
>            }
>         System.out.println(arrrList);
>      } }
> ```